# Schema-bound View Index creation fails due to constant varchar column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.1000.169), I've created a view with `SCHEMABINDING` as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[sprov_login] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT   
        Name,
        Email AS [LoginId],
        'foo' AS [Last_name],
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS cBig
    FROM 
        dbo.bill_product
    GROUP BY 
        DBName, [Email] 
GO
```

Then I try to create an index on it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V10 
ON dbo.[sprov_login] (Name, LoginId);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8668, Level 16, State 0, Line 212
> Cannot create the clustered index 'IDX_V10' on view 'BillingDB.dbo.sprov_login' because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column. Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column from select list.

If I remove

```
 'foo' AS [Last_name]
```

from the view definition, the index can be created with no errors.

I have also tried instead adding `Last_name` to the unique index,

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V10 
ON dbo.[sprov_login] (DBName, LoginId, Last_name);
```

but I get the same error message.

How can I create this view and index with a constant value `varchar` column?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this static string in your example is actually an expression returning a string as having a static text like this makes no sense.

If this is the case, you can add this computation as a computed column to your original table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.bill_product
ADD [Last_name] AS 'foo'


CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[sprov_login] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT   
        Name,
        Email AS [LoginId],
        [Last_name],
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS cBig
    FROM 
        dbo.bill_product
    GROUP BY 
        Name, [Last_name], [Email]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V10 
ON dbo.[sprov_login] (Name, LoginId);
```

If you can't change the table, create a new one:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DummyData
(
    [Last_name] VARCHAR(3)
);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.DummyData ([Last_name])
VALUES ('foo')

GO


CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[sprov_login] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT   
        Name,
        Email AS [LoginId],
        D.[Last_name],
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS cBig
    FROM 
        dbo.bill_product
    INNER JOIN dbo.DummyData D
        ON 1 = 1
    GROUP BY 
        Name, D.[Last_name], [Email]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V10 
ON dbo.[sprov_login] (Name, LoginId);
```

Comment: I can't make changes to the original table the view is based on.  Do you have any insight as to why the index can't be created in the presence of a static value?

Comment: Well, I guess the `string` is treat by the engine as an expression - it's basically not part of a group clause and not an aggregation, so it seems is hard to understand how to treat this value. Also, having such static `value` does not make any sense at all as you can add it during the `select` from the view itself. Check the edit.

Comment: thanks for your help and explanation, but I'm going to keep searching for another solution - this one offends me on a personal level ;)

Comment: @Black Sure. let me know if you find another work around. I am curios.